# Provide Terminal Input to `gexec.Session`

Tags: go, ginkgo, gomega

I need to provide input to an `exec.Command` that is started by Gomega's `gexec.Session`.

The command I'm executing is currently complaining that "stty: stdin isn't a terminal". How can I provide input to the spawned process that looks like it comes from a terminal?

Comment: "exec.Command(your cmd).Stdin = ReaderWhichYouWantToReadInput" will not suite?

Comment: If it's looking for a tty, have you tried connecting it you your stdin?